# Scroll into div, prevent second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to do the following. I created this fiddle to show what I am trying to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/c4xcb98w/1/

If the user clicks on clickable element link "Click 6", it should be scrolled to the element in the div .location-wrapper. This works, but what I do not understand is that it scrolls back to the top if click the same link again.

Additionally if I clicked on click6 and it scrolled down, and then I click on "click8" it scrolls up again, but not to div number 8.

Does somebody know how I can achieve that if it has scrolled and I click the same trigger again it should do nothing and if click another trigger it should scroll to that div?

```js
$('.click_6').click(function(e) {
  $('.location-wrapper').animate({
    scrollTop: ($("#box_6").offset().top)
  }, 'slow');
});

$('.click_8').click(function(e) {
  $('.location-wrapper').animate({
    scrollTop: ($("#box_8").offset().top)
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.location-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.location-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 315px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click_6">click6</div>
<div class="click_8">click8</div>
<div id="map">
</div>

<div class="location-wrapper">
  <div class="location-box" id="box_1">#1</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_2">#2</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_3">#3</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_4">#4</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_5">#5</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_6">#6</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_7">#7</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_8">#8</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_9">#9</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_10">#10</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_11">#11</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_12">#12</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_13">#13</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_14">#14</div>
  <div class="location-box" id="box_15">#15</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) gives you the coordinates relative to the `document`, so you have to take into consideration the `scrollTop` value of the wrapper.

The following code is not optimal, but it'll give you a good direction:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4xcb98w/2/)

```
$('.click_6').click(function(e) {
              $('.location-wrapper').animate({
                  scrollTop: ($("#box_6").offset().top +
                              $("#box_6").offsetParent().scrollTop())},
                  'slow');
});

$('.click_8').click(function(e) {
              $('.location-wrapper').animate({
                  scrollTop: ($("#box_8").offset().top +
                              $("#box_8").offsetParent().scrollTop())},
                  'slow');
});
```

---

BTW, [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) is more suitable when you need the coordinates relative to the parent's top (the wrapper).

So this code is probably better:

```
$('.click_6').click(function(e) {
              $('.location-wrapper').animate({
                  scrollTop: ($("#box_6").poition().top +
                              $("#box_6").offsetParent().scrollTop())},
                  'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ive edited your code. https://jsfiddle.net/c4xcb98w/4/ here is a working demo.

```
var box6 = $("#box_6").offset().top;
var box8 = $("#box_8").offset().top;
$('.click_6').click(function(e) {
              $('.location-wrapper').stop().animate({
                  scrollTop: box6},
                  'slow');
});

$('.click_8').click(function(e) {
              $('.location-wrapper').stop().animate({
                  scrollTop: box8},
                  'slow');
});
```

i think it fails to get your location_box offset.top on initialize

Comment: This is a nice solution, but OP should notice it won't work for dynamic content, because the offset is calculated only once.